# C# WPF, Date Picker. Only following days

Tags: c#, wpf

I want date picker which shows only current day and following only. Not past
THanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you can do it.

```
yourDatePickersName.DisplayDateStart = DateTime.Today;
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use something like the following with the .NET 4 [DatePicker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datepicker%28v=VS.100%29.aspx):

```
xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
...
<DatePicker DisplayDateStart="{x:Static system:DateTime.Now}" />
```

Comment: This is a better approach considering it's somehow related to restricting UI functionality.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [DatePicker.DisplayDateStart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datepicker.displaydatestart%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)?